# I get a scheme missing error with cron

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, cron

when I use this to download a file from an ftp server:

```
wget ftp://blah:blah@ftp.haha.com/"$(date +%Y%m%d -d yesterday)-blah.gz" /myFolder/Documents/"$(date +%Y%m%d -d yesterday)-blah.gz"
```

It says `"20131022-blah.gz saved"` (it downloads fine), however I get this:

`/myFolder/Documents/20131022-blah.gz: Scheme missing (I believe this error prevents it from saving the file in /myFolder/Documents/).`

I have no idea why this is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save the filename in a variable first:

```
OUT=$(date +%Y%m%d -d yesterday)-blah.gz
```

and then use `-O` switch for output file:

```
wget ftp://blah:blah@ftp.haha.com/"$OUT" -O /myFolder/Documents/"$OUT"
```

- Without the `-O`, the output file name looks like a second file/URL to fetch, but it's missing `http://` or `ftp://` or some other scheme to tell `wget` how to access it. (Thanks @chepner)
- If `wget` takes time to download a big file then minute will change and your download filename will be different from filename being saved.

Comment: Without the `-O`, the output file name looks like a second file/URL to fetch, but it's missing `http://` or `ftp://` or some other scheme to tell `wget` how to access it.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks much appreciated, let me add it to answer.

Comment: Ok so now it works.. however it is a .tar.gz and I am using tar -zxvf "OUT" to unzip the file. This works when I do it manually.. however when I run it through cron it does not work.. should i open this in another thread or are these related?

Comment: @user2883071: Please open a new question for that problem since that problem seems unrelated with this problem.

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had it working with the npm module `http-server`.

And discovered that I simply had a leading space before `http://`.

So this was wrong `" http://localhost:8080/archive.zip"`.

Changed to working solution `"http://localhost:8080/archive.zip"`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used in cpanel:

```
wget https://www.blah.com.br/path/to/cron/whatever
```